# How many times Twilio will try sending texts to a number which has been, out of range, network disconnected?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to understand before twilio generated error #30003, how many times it tried reaching the end cellphone #, if the subscriber's cell phone is out of range, not available? switched off, temporary disconnected and so on?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer here.

Twilio only spends a few seconds trying to deliver an SMS message before determining that the message delivery failed. The exact amount of time varies based on which carrier is used for the delivery.

So if your first attempt to deliver a message failed but you want to try again later, you should add some logic to your application that resends the message to Twilio at a time that makes sense.

Note that Twilio [does not charge you](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/will-i-be-charged-if-twilio-encounters-an-error-when-sending-an-sms?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon) for failed attempts to send a message.

Let me know if that helps!